# Induced Matrix Norms

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

I have already proved $\|A\|_\infty \le \|A\|_2$.  And I have that

$\|A\| = \sup_{x\ne 0}\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|} $

However I am having difficulty proving that $\|A\|_\infty\le \sqrt{n}\|A\|_2$.

Comment: Question: what is $x$?

Comment: Check my edits.

Answer (score 1):

Before we start this proof we need to know that $\|x\|_\infty \le \|x\|_2 \le \sqrt{n}\|x\|_\infty,$ which is a different proof altogether:

Recall that $\|x\|_\infty = max\{|x_1|,|x_2|,\ldots,|x_n|\}$ and that $\|x\|_2 = (|x_1|^2 + |x_2|^2 + \cdots + |x_n|^2)^{1/2}.$ Without loss of generality let $|x_i|$ be the maximum element such that $\|x\|_\infty = |x_i|$. It should be clear that $|x_i| \le (|x_1|^2 + |x_2|^2 + \cdots + |x_i|^2 + \cdots +|x_n|^2)^{1/2},$ you can square both sides to quickly see that it is true.
Thus $\|x\|_\infty \le \|x\|_2.$

To show the other side we will show that $\frac{\|x\|_2}{\sqrt{n}} \le \|x\|_\infty.$
$$
\frac{\|x\|_2}{\sqrt{n}} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\left(|x_1|^2 + |x_2|^2 + \cdots + |x_n|^2 \right)}.
$$
$
\frac{1}{n}\left(|x_1|^2 + |x_2|^2 + \cdots + |x_n|^2 \right)
$ is the average of the squares, denoted $x_{ave}^2.$ Then $\sqrt{x_{ave}^2} = x_{ave}$.

This amount is certainly less than or equal to $x_{max}$, which shows then that
$$
\frac{\|x\|_2}{\sqrt{n}} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\left(|x_1|^2 + |x_2|^2 + \cdots + |x_n|^2 \right)} = x_{ave} \le x_{max} = \|x\|_\infty.
$$

Now we have shown $\frac{\|x\|_2}{\sqrt{n}} \le \|x\|_\infty, \Rightarrow \|x\|_2 \le \sqrt{n}\|x\|_\infty.$

With this tool we can now prove  $\|A\|_{\infty} \le \sqrt{n}\|A\|_2,$ we will show that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\|A\|_{\infty} \le \|A\|_2.$

Observe that we can write: $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\|A\|_\infty = sup_{x\,\in\,X}\frac{\|Ax\|_\infty}{\sqrt{n}\|x\|_\infty} \le sup_{x\,\in\,X}\frac{\|Ax\|_\infty}{\|x\|_2} \le sup_{x\,\in\,X}\frac{\|Ax\|_2}{\|x\|_2} = \|A\|_2.$$

Which then tells us that $\|A\|_{\infty} \le \sqrt{n}\|A\|_2,$ as we had hoped.

Comment: When LaTeXing norms, I prefer to use `\|x\|`, which gives you $\|x\|$ as opposed to $||x||$.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, something I wouldn't have known to do previously.

Comment: @Mitch Just one thing that isn't quite clear how is ||A_x|| inf >sup||Ax||inf . Its the inequality on the second line

Comment: @user147825 Sorry I realized there was a mistake in the original write-up. I sought an alternative method instead that I think is a bit more robust. Let me know if you have any other questions.